# How to determine how many unique other items an integer has been with in a list of lists of lists?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've got a list of lists, with integers in it, like this:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[3, 7, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6]]]
```

Given the integer 1, I would like some way to make a function that will return

```
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

My current method is:

```
bigList = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[3, 7, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6]]]
hasBeenWith = []
integer = 1
for medList in bigList:
    for smallList in medList:
        if integer in smallList:
            hasBeenWith = hasBeenWith + list(set(smallList) -   set(hasBeenWith))
```

I know this  is a naive algorithm. What is a better, more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I don't quite get the question. Could you clarify the "rule" that causes the return of the list by inputting the integer 1?

Comment: @Jerrybibo I want the return to be all the other items 1 has been in a list with. So if I put in 2, I would get 1, 3, 4, and 6, because those are all the integers 2 is in a list with. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: You are looking for an output set, not really a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit shorter, and still pretty readable.  Since you only care about the bottom level lists, it would be more readable IMO if you had a function that flattened the nested list structure down to a single iterable of lists (basically what all the `chain`'s and list comprehensions are doing.  Then you could just have a single list comprehension that iterates through the flattened structure.

```
from itertools import chain

num = 1
biglist = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[3, 7, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6]]]
been_with = set(chain(*[x for x in chain(*biglist) if num in x])) - {num}
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> set(integer for medList in bigList for smallList in medList for integer in smallList if 1 in smallList)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
```

You can use a set comprehension to loop through all the lists and pick out the elements of the lists that contain 1. Notice that the `for` loops are in the same order as in your code, they're just all in one line.

```
>>> set(integer for medList in bigList for smallList in medList for integer in smallList if 1 in smallList and integer != 1)
{2, 3, 4, 6}
```

Then you'd want to exclude `1` from the result.

```
>>> list(set(integer for medList in bigList for smallList in medList for integer in smallList if 1 in smallList and integer != 1))
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

And if you want the result as a list, convert it to one at the end. Working with a set and switching to a list at the end is more efficient than storing the intermediate results as lists.

By the way, the numbers came out in order here, but that's not guaranteed to happen. Sets aren't ordered, so it's just a coincidence that they're sorted. If you want them in order, add in a call to `sorted()`.

Comment: Thanks! This looks way nicer than mine.